# Should I use `const T&` instead of `T&&` in my code like stl

Tags: c++, reference, stl

I have writing code like:

```cpp
template<bool B, typename IfT, typename ThenT>
using conditional_t = std::conditional_t<B, IfT, ThenT>;

template <bool B,
  typename IfT, typename ThenT>
constexpr auto conditional_v(IfT&& t1, ThenT&& t2)
  -> conditional_t<B, IfT, ThenT> {
  if constexpr (B) {
    return t1;
  } else {
    return t2;
  }
}
```

If passed by value like `conditional_v<true>(0, 1)`, we can get

```cpp
template<>
inline constexpr conditional_t<true, int, int> conditional_v<true, int, int>(int && t1, int && t2)
{
  if constexpr(true) {
    return t1;
  }

}
```

if passed by reference like `conditional_v<true>(i, j)`, we will get

```cpp
template<>
inline constexpr conditional_t<true, int &, int &> conditional_v<true, int &, int &>(int & t1, int & t2)
{
  if constexpr(true) {
    return t1;
  }

}
```

When I refer to the stl, for example the `max`

```cpp
template< class T >
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );
```

They are mostly passed by `const T&` instead of `T&&`.

So I got the question: Should I use `const T&` in my situation(just like conditional_t, conditional_v designed to choose one initial value at comipler time(int, literal string, etc...)).

Comment: `max` is not supposed to change `a` or `b` so `const&` makes sense.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, that's the point, thx. Anyway, when no optimization applied, if `(int)0` is passed, pass by value if more efficient than reference. So if it make scense when to distinct by value or by reference?

Comment: If it's important to get optimized code without using the compiler's optimizing option one would have to create a specialization for small types. I wouldn't worry about that and only look at what the code looks like when actually using the optimizing option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use `const T&` instead of `T&&` in my code like stl?

If I understand your question correctly, you should use `T&&` to enable forwarding:

```
#include <utility>

template<bool B, class T, class F>
constexpr decltype(auto) conditional_v(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    if constexpr(B) return std::forward<T>(t);
    else            return std::forward<F>(f);
}
```

Comment: Using `std::move` was thought to disable [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)。And this seems all are moved or copied without any chance of return reference.

Comment: @Dreamonly I'm not sure I understand what you're after then. You could make the return value `&` or `&&`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Ted, the four `conditional_v` can combined to the first one only, with `std::forward` instead of `std::move`, and `std::move` will disable the optimization NRVO if not a reference.

Comment: @Dreamonly Just replacing `move` with `forward` won't work or what would that look like? I don't see NRVO being an issue. The incomming reference is passed straight through the function as-is.

Comment: Of cource, it will not work just replace with `forward`, the return should been `conditional_t<B, IfT, ThenT>`. And as I know std::move may disable the NRVO.

Comment: @Dreamonly Facepalm - I think I get what you meant with the forwarding. The NRVO part I'm a bit unclear about though. The references should be passed through the function as-is without creating an object. That has to be done at the call-site. Anyway, I removed all that and replaced it with what I currently believe you want :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's it ^_^. And almost like what I asked. I have thought it is not good to make the conditional_v with constexpr if, as it seems need the initialization when args passed to the conditional_v.

Comment: @Dreamonly Great! !  I don't folliow the constexpr reasoning though so I'm unable to say anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

T&& was introduced to avoid unnecessary copies by "stealing" the passed object resources. Suppose object rhs has a pointer to some allocated resource rhs.p then a typical use would be

```
void steal (T&& rhs){
  p=rhs.p;
  rhs.p=nullptr;
}
```

Since in your case `std::max` does not intend to change the parameters there is no reason to pass the arguments by rvalue reference. Also you will not be able to use it with lvalue references.
The `const T&` allow us to pass temporaries in addition to named variables. For example

```
struct Test {};
Test returnObject(){
   Test t;
   return t;
}

int main(){
Test x;
Test& y=x;
Test&& z=x;//error cannot bind rvalue to lvalue
Test& r=returnObject();// error: cannot bind lvalue to rvalue
const Test& a=returnObject();// OK
Test&& b=returbObject();// OK
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, what I eactly want is if it is a literal, `conditional_v` gets the literal like move, no other constraints like `const` on it, if it is a variable,  `conditional_v` get the reference. Get the data as it original like.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
int foo = bar(); // some function that returns a value we don't know
int foo2 = std::max(foo, 100); // make sure it's no more than 100
```

How would you write that code if `std::max` took it's arguments by `&&`?

Comment: Nitpick: "_make sure it's no more than 100_" - should be: make sure it's at least 100

Comment: @Marshall Chow Well, it is OK with `inline constexpr conditional_t<true, int &, int> conditional_v<true, int &, int>(int & t1, int && t2)`.  Maybe I didn't get your point?

Comment: @Marshall Chow You are right, thanks for your comment. My situation is special like `A get(A a) { return a; }` with `constexper if`. For `max`, we need more meta calculation for the return, none const reference is not legal in the situation with `100`.

Comment: @Dreamonly If you re-read your question, you should see that you asked specifically about the STL. So an answer that uses `std::max` is more appropriate than an answer that applies to your situation. Make sure you ask what you mean to ask.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you very much, realy the bad description before. I have changed my question focus on my situation.